# Fire continuous curl commands in a one minute window

Tags: curl

I am trying to test a throttling policy enforced by my api gateway using curl as follows...

```
  cmd="curl -vvv --insecure --request GET \
    --url 'https://myUrl?mySearchParameter=blah' \
    --header 'x-transactionid: 550e8400' > /dev/null"

  while true; do eval "$cmd"; sleep 0; done
```

This continually fires off requests at my api and I can see the throttling working.

How can I tweak my curl commands to match the following requirements:

- Restrict the test to a 1 minute window
- Count the number of
  successful requests during the one minute window

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a specialized tool for that, like [`ab`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) (in `apache2-utils` package), or [`wrk`](https://github.com/wg/wrk)?